# Count all working days in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have B column that containing all days:

```
B40: Sun
B41: Mon
B42: Tue
B43: Wed
B44: Thu
B45: Fri
B46: Sat
B47: Sun
B48: Mon
...
B69
```

I want to sum all the occurrences that has a working day. thought of trying to one, but it's not working

```
=COUNTIF(B40:B69,{"Sun"; "Mon"; "Tue"; "Wed";"Thu"})
```

Also tried this one:

```
=COUNTIFS(B40:B69,  "<>Fri") + COUNTIFS(B40:B69,  "<>Sat")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get both of your formulas to work if you change them a bit

```
=arrayformula(sum(COUNTIF(B40:B69,{"Sun"; "Mon"; "Tue"; "Wed";"Thu"})))
```

or

```
=sumproduct(COUNTIF(B40:B69,{"Sun"; "Mon"; "Tue"; "Wed";"Thu"}))
```

so you add the counts for Sun, Mon etc.

```
=COUNTIFS(B40:B69,  "<>Fri",B40:B69,"<>Sat",B40:B69,"<>")
```

so you exclude Fridays, Saturdays and any empty cells.